# How do i display images or files using handlebars after successfully completing the process through multer

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, handlebars.js

I have used `multer` for performing file uploads  and i want to display the images which are uploaded to the database using `express-handlebars`
Here is my code  `index.handlebars`

```
  {{#each ideas}}
<div class="card card-body mb-2">

 <img src="uploads/{{ideas.filename}}" height="230" width="300">
 </div>

 <div class="card card-body mb-2">
  <p>{{text}}</p>
 </div>

 <a class="btn btn-dark btn-block mb-2" href="/ideas/edit/{{id}}">Edit</a>
<form method="post" action="/ideas/{{id}}?_method=DELETE">
  <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="DELETE">
  <input type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-block" value="Delete">
  </form>
 </div>
 {{else}}
 <p>No video ideas listed</p>
{{/each}}

 File Upload Code

  router.post('/', (req, res) => {
 upload(req, res, (err) => {
  if (err) {
  return res.end('error request file');
   }
  var data = new Idea({
   text: req.body.text,
   image: req.file.originalname,
   path : req.body.text
});
data.save().then((result) => {
  //res.send(result);
  //res.redirect('/')
  console.log('saved')
});
  console.log(req.file);
   //res.end('upload file success');
   //res.redirect('/')
    res.redirect('/')
   console.log('success');
 });
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the answer after an exhaustive research, whosoever uploads an image 
      using handlebars here is the code

```html
{{#each ideas}}
  <div class="card card-body mb-2">
    <img src="./uploads/{{image}}" width="200" height="100">
  </div>


 <a class="btn btn-dark btn-block mb-2" href="/ideas/edit/{{id}}">Edit</a>
 <form method="post" action="/ideas/{{id}}?_method=DELETE">
      <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="DELETE">
      <input type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-block" value="Delete">
 </form>
       </div>
 {{else}}
        <p>No video ideas listed</p>
{{/each}}
```